# Coldfusion - Firstdata Global Gateway - Need help getting started

Tags: api, coldfusion, firstdata

I’m using Coldfusion 9,0,0,251028 on Windows 7 64-bit.

I'm trying to change credit card processors for a website.  I've read the integration guide for the Web Service API  v 4.0, but it doesn't give me much in the way of how I integrate with coldfusion to build the xml that gets enclosed in SOAP and sent.

I've talked to Firstdata's second level support and was told they don't help with programming beyond troubleshooting error codes.  They also told me they have no forum concerning the web service API.

What kind of tags in coldfusion would I use to start this transaction?  Does anyone know where I could find an example or instructions besides the web service api integration guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some recommended reading on doing SOAP with ColdFusion:

[Making SOAP Web Service Requests With ColdFusion And CFHTTP](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-Making-SOAP-Web-Service-Requests-With-ColdFusion-And-CFHTTP.htm)

[SOAP Request Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6c84.html)

[Troubleshooting SOAP Requests and Responses](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13a13-7fde.html)

I've always found SOAP to be a pain in the ass, but if that's the only way to go, the three links above should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at cfobject and cfinvoke. I assume you have the WSDL url, so the first thing I would do is try that like this:

```
<cfobject webservice = "WSDL URL" name = "testCall" />
<cfdump var="#testCall#"/>
```

This should show you the available methods. Then you would call those message using cfinvoke:

```
<cfinvoke webservice = "#testCall#" method = "methodName" returnvariable="returnData" />
```

Then you could use the return data however you need. But a god start is to just dump it out and see what it looks like.

```
<cfdump var="#returnData#" />
```